# Docker container with macvlan can't be pinged by other host

Tags: docker, docker-network, macvlan

I know I can't ping the macvlan interface from the same host, but I can't ping my container's macvlan interface from hosts on a different subnet (even though they're connected via a router).

Host IP: 10.8.2.132/22

Macvlan container IP: 10.8.2.250/22

Other host IP: 10.4.16.141/22

```
Ping FROM 10.8.2.132 TO 10.4.16.141 is successful

Ping FROM 10.8.2.250 TO 10.4.16.141 is successful

Ping FROM 10.4.16.141 TO 10.8.2.132 is successful

Ping FROM 10.4.16.141 TO 10.8.2.250 fails with 100% packet loss
```

ip route get 10.8.2.250 shows that there is a known route:

```
10.8.2.250 via 10.4.16.1 dev eth0  src 10.4.16.141 
 cache  mtu 1500 hoplimit 64
```

How can I go about debugging this?

The docker macvlan network was created with:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=10.8.0.0/22 --gateway=10.8.0.1 -o parent=em1 macnet
```

and when I run the container I specifically add "--ip=10.8.2.250"

Comment: Did you figure it out? Got the same problem on Synology Docker version 18.09.8, build 2c0a67b.

Comment: It's working for me now, so this scenario is possible with Macvlan. I misconfigured Policy Based Routing on my router, which was the reason I couldn't ping the Macvlan containers from another subnet.